# Is it possible to return "text()" in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I would like to return `text(x,y,n,n)` in a function.

Currently, this is how my code looks like:

```java
public void myText(){
    text("Hello World", 20, 20);
}
```

But, I would love to have a Syntax like this:

```java
public text myText() {
   return ("Hello World", 20, 20);
}
```

or

```java
public myText(){
   return (text("Hello World", 20, 20));
}
```

Well, I have been trying to do lots of researches about this issue, but still, the result is `negative`.

Is it possible to do that or is there any other similarity?

Answer (score 2):

You can render the text to a [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) object. e.g.:

```
void setup() {
    size(200, 200);
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  PGraphics pgText = myText();

  image(pgText, 20, 30);
  image(pgText, 20, 60);
}

public PGraphics myText() {

    String s = "Hello World";
    int h = 20;
    textSize(h);
    float w = textWidth(s);

    PGraphics pg = createGraphics(int(w), h);
    pg.beginDraw();
    pg.text(s, 0, h);
    pg.endDraw();

    return pg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for **classes**.

You can create a class that encapsulates the data you care about. Something like this:

```
class MyText {
  String message;
  int x;
  int y;

  public MyText(String message, int x, int y) {
    this.message = message;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void draw(){
    text(message, x, y);
  }
}
```

Then you could use that class in your sketch:

```
MyText myText;

void setup() {
  myText = new MyText("hello", 25, 25);
}

void draw() {
  myText.draw();
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating classes in Processing.